# Questions in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $A \in\mathbb(C)^{p\times n}, C \in \mathbb(C)^{p\times q}$. Show that you cannot have more than one matrix $B\in\mathbb(C)^{n\times q}$ s.t. both of the properties hold:

1) $AB = C$ and

2) $B^{H}\vec{v}=0$ for every vector $\vec{v}\in N_{A}$.

Directions:

a) Assume there are two matrices B1 and B2 such that properties 1 and 2 hold. Show that the columns of D=B1−B2 are in $N_{A}$ because of property 1.

b) Show that $D^{H}D=0$ because of property 2.

a) Assume that there is indeed two matrices B1 and B2 such that property 1 holds.

Further consider,

$AB_{1} - AB_{2} = C-C$

$\implies$ $A(B_{1}-B_{2}) = 0$

let $D = (B_{1}-B_{2})$, such that

$AD = 0$

Note that A $\in$ $\mathbb(C)^{pxn}$ and $B_{1},B_{2}$ $\in$ $\mathbb(C)^{nxq}$, since subtraction does not change the size of the resulting matrix, then D $\in$ $\mathbb(C)^{nxq}$, thus by matrix multiplication O $\in$ $\mathbb(C)^{pxq}$ matrix. Now I don't know how to show that the columns of D are in $N_{A}$ because of property 1; shouldn't they automatically be because matrix multiplication gives me the zero matrix?

b) We take a similar approach such that

$(B_{1}^{H}-B_{2}^{H})\vec{v}=0$

$\implies(B_{1}-B_{2})^{H}\vec{v}=0$

$\implies(D)^{H}\vec{v}=0$

Now, can't I just simply multiply by D from the right such that I obtain,

$\implies(D)^{H}\vec{v}D=0D$

$\implies(D)^{H}D\vec{v}=0$

Then since $D\in N_{A}$, shouldn't I just get that

$(D)^{H}D=0$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exist $B_1$ and $B_2$ satisfying the two properties. Set $D=B_1-B_2$. Then $AD=0$. Thus, for every $v\in\mathbb{C}^q$, $Dv\in N(A)$. Note that $D$ satisfies property 2, which implies $D^H(Dv)=0$, for every $v$.

Can you finish?

Comment: So that $\vec{v}\in\mathbb{C}$, $Dv\in N(A)$, would be for part (a) or for part (b)?

Comment: @lastgunslinger Part (a) ends with $AD=0$.

Comment: Ok then, then this means that the columns of D are N(A) correct, thus, I would get $D^{H}(Dv)=D^{H}(0)=0$

Comment: @lastgunslinger No, $Dv$ is not necessarily $0$; it's $D^H(Dv)=0$, because of property 2. This implies $D^HD=0$ and so…